# Handle cell parsing in DataGridView custon column

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have defined a custom column for DataGridView to display values in Hex. All it does is to format the text and specify the font.

(For historic reasons in VB.NET :-))

```
Public Class clsDgvHexColumn
  Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

  Private mFont             As System.Drawing.Font

  public sub New
    MyBase.CellTemplate = new clsDgvHexColumnCell
    mFont = New System.Drawing.Font ( "Consolas", 10 )
  End Sub

  Public Property Font As Font
    Get
      Return mFont
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Font)
      mFont = value
      Me.DefaultCellStyle.Font = mFont
    End Set
  End Property

End Class

Public Class clsDgvHexColumnCell
  Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxCell

  Protected Overrides Function GetFormattedValue ( ByVal value                        As Object, _
                                                   ByVal rowIndex                     As Integer, _
                                                   ByRef cellStyle                    As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle, _
                                                   ByVal valueTypeConverter           As System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, _
                                                   ByVal formattedValueTypeConverter  As System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, _
                                                   ByVal context                      As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorContexts ) As Object
    Return String.Format ( "0x{0:X4}", value )
  End Function

End Class
```

To handle input I have defined a handler for the CellParsing event on the grid.

```
Private Sub dgvValues_CellParsing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs) Handles dgvValues.CellParsing

  If     dgvValues.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "NewDAC" _
  OrElse dgvValues.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "NewOffset" _
  OrElse dgvValues.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "New80PercentValue" _
  Then

    If e IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
      Try
        Dim InputString   As String = TryCast(e.Value, String)
        Dim newValue      As Int32  = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(newValue).ConvertFrom(InputString)
        Dim bytes         As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(newValue)

        If e.DesiredType.Equals(GetType(UInt16)) Then
          e.Value = BitConverter.ToUInt16 ( bytes, 0 )
        ElseIf e.DesiredType.Equals(GetType(Int16)) Then
          e.Value = BitConverter.ToInt16 ( bytes, 0 )
        ElseIf e.DesiredType.Equals(GetType(UInt32)) Then
          e.Value = BitConverter.ToUInt32 ( bytes, 0 )
        ElseIf e.DesiredType.Equals(GetType(Int32)) Then
          e.Value = newValue
        End If

        e.ParsingApplied = True
      Catch

      End Try
    End If

  End If

End Sub
```

This basically works, but I would very much prefer to completely encapsulate the cell parsing logic within the custom column.

That way I could just select the column type and everything would work, without any special handling in the form containing the grid.

Is there any way to handle the CellParsing within the custom column (or cell) class?

Comment: Override [`ParseFormattedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.parseformattedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I think that is the solution. Is there a way to get the type of bound data (Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32)? If not, I will probably make separate column types, HexColumnInt16, HexColumnUInt16, HexColumnInt32 and HexColumnUInt32.

Comment: [`ValueType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx) property (at least this is what the default implementation is using :)

Comment: Thanks, that works.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ivan Stoev's suggestions, this is my new custom column definition:

```
Public Class clsDgvHexColumn
  Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

  Private mFont             As System.Drawing.Font

  public sub New
    MyBase.CellTemplate = new clsDgvHexColumnCell
    mFont = New System.Drawing.Font ( "Consolas", 10 )
  End Sub

  Public Property Font As Font
    Get
      Return mFont
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Font)
      mFont = value
      Me.DefaultCellStyle.Font = mFont
    End Set
  End Property

End Class

Public Class clsDgvHexColumnCell
  Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxCell

  Protected Overrides Function GetFormattedValue ( ByVal value                        As Object, _
                                                   ByVal rowIndex                     As Integer, _
                                                   ByRef cellStyle                    As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle, _
                                                   ByVal valueTypeConverter           As System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, _
                                                   ByVal formattedValueTypeConverter  As System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, _
                                                   ByVal context                      As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorContexts ) As Object
    Return String.Format ( "0x{0:X4}", value )
  End Function

  Public Overrides Function ParseFormattedValue ( ByVal formattedValue              As Object, 
                                                  ByVal cellStyle                   As DataGridViewCellStyle, 
                                                  ByVal formattedValueTypeConverter As TypeConverter, 
                                                  ByVal valueTypeConverter          As TypeConverter ) As Object

    Dim InputString As String = TryCast(formattedValue, String)
    Dim newValue    As Int32  = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(newValue).ConvertFrom(InputString)
    Dim bytes       As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(newValue)

    If ValueType.Equals(GetType(UInt16)) Then
      Return BitConverter.ToUInt16 ( bytes, 0 )
    ElseIf ValueType.Equals(GetType(Int16)) Then
      Return BitConverter.ToInt16 ( bytes, 0 )
    ElseIf ValueType.Equals(GetType(UInt32)) Then
      Return BitConverter.ToUInt32 ( bytes, 0 )
    ElseIf ValueType.Equals(GetType(Int32)) Then
      Return newValue
    Else
      Return newValue
    End If

  End Function

End Class
```

At present, this seems to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your requirements correctly, `You need to encapsulate the handler logic inside the custom column class`?. Then something like this would be feasible, put the sub inside the class so your class should look something like this

```
Public Class clsDgvHexColumn
  Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

  Private mFont             As System.Drawing.Font

  public sub New
    MyBase.CellTemplate = new clsDgvHexColumnCell
    mFont = New System.Drawing.Font ( "Consolas", 10 )
  End Sub

  Public Property Font As Font
    Get
      Return mFont
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Font)
      mFont = value
      Me.DefaultCellStyle.Font = mFont
    End Set
  End Property

Public Shared Sub Handler_CellParsing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs)
      Dim dgv as Your_Type //This is the type of dgvValues (which is DataGridView) I suppose, Replace Your_Type appropriately
      dgv = CType(sender,Your_Type)
      If     dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "NewDAC" _
      OrElse dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "NewOffset" _
      OrElse dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "New80PercentValue" _
      Then

    If e IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
      Try
        Dim InputString   As String = TryCast(e.Value, String)
        Dim newValue      As Int32  = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(newValue).ConvertFrom(InputString)
        Dim bytes         As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(newValue)

        If e.DesiredType.Equals(GetType(UInt16)) Then
          e.Value = BitConverter.ToUInt16 ( bytes, 0 )
        ElseIf e.DesiredType.Equals(GetType(Int16)) Then
          e.Value = BitConverter.ToInt16 ( bytes, 0 )
        ElseIf e.DesiredType.Equals(GetType(UInt32)) Then
          e.Value = BitConverter.ToUInt32 ( bytes, 0 )
        ElseIf e.DesiredType.Equals(GetType(Int32)) Then
          e.Value = newValue
        End If

        e.ParsingApplied = True
      Catch

      End Try
    End If

  End If

End Sub
End Class
```

And when you create a DataGridView or whatever, just add the event handler to the Control like so,

```
AddHandler dgvValues.CellParsing , AddressOf clsDgvHexColumn.Handler_CellParsing
```

However, I may be wrong on my interpretation of your goal.

Comment: That would be OK if I could place the AddHandler call in the code of the custom column class. I would have to figure where to do that. Also the column-check would have to check itself (rather than specific named columns). What I want, is to select the type of the column and require no other custom code in the form.